# I am not able to get the desired output from this code for finding minimum absolute difference

Tags: c++, heap

The code I have written so far is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void heapify(int arr[], int n, int i) {
    int smallest = i; 
    int l = 2 * i + 1; 
    int r = 2 * i + 2; 

    if (l < n && abs(arr[l] - arr[i]) < abs(arr[smallest] - arr[i]))
        smallest = l;

    if (r < n && abs(arr[r] - arr[i]) < abs(arr[smallest] - arr[i]))
        smallest = r;

    if (smallest != i) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[smallest]);
        heapify(arr, n, smallest);
    }
}

int minAbsoluteDifference(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);

    int minDiff = abs(arr[1] - arr[0]);

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        minDiff = min(minDiff, abs(arr[i] - arr[0]));
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }

    return minDiff;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int minDiff = minAbsoluteDifference(arr, n);
    cout << "Minimum absolute difference between any two distinct elements in the array is: " << minDiff << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For a test case

```
-5 -3 -1 0 2
```

the output should be 1 as the difference between -1 and 0 is the least i.e 1 but the output comes out as 2.
Where am I going wrong in the code, any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: ChatGPT? (openai classifier: possibly AI generated) I mean it's very nice code, but I'm not sure how it applies to the problem at hand. Can you explain the idea behind your solution?

Comment: Please first explain the algorithm you *intended* to implement, because this code makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the presented code is too complex for the task.

Let us first think on how this could be solved. The naive approach would be to compare each value of the array with other values, calculate the delta and then take the absolute value. The result would be a quadratic time complexity that would take too long.

So, the first design choice will be too sort the elements in the array. Then there will be always a smaller element in front of a larger element and the delta between the larger and the smaller will always be positive.

After sorting, we can simply calculate the delta between the next and the previous value, and compare against the current minimum. If we find a new minimum, then we can remember that.

Additional hint: In your main you used the statement `int arr[n];` This is a VLA, a variable length array, which is not part of the C++ language. (Some compiler ignore that and compile it anyway). So, it is not allowed. You can simply use the drop in replacement `std::vector` which has the additional advantage of knowing its size.

Then the algorithm is easy:

- Get the number of elements to read
- Read numbers
- Sort them
- Handle special case of 1 element
- in a loop, calculate delta between next element and previous element
- Check, if delta is a new minimum and remember that

The straight forward implementation may look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

int minAbsoluteDifference(std::vector<int>& v) {
    int minDelta = 0;
    // Sanity check for empty vector
    if (not v.empty()) {

        // Special case for vector with one element
        if (v.size() == 1)

            // Then simply return the first elemnt
            minDelta = std::abs(v[0]);

        else {
            // Vector contains now at least 2 elements
            // First sort
            std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

            // Initialize minDelta initially to a maximum value
            minDelta = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

            // Now in a loop, calculate all deltas
            for (std::size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {

                // Calculate delta, Will always be positive, because of previous sorting
                const int delta = v[i] - v[i - 1];

                // Check for a new ninimum delta
                if (delta < minDelta)
                    // And, if found, remeber new nin delta
                    minDelta = delta;
            }
        }
    }
    return minDelta;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "\nEnter the size of the array: ";

    // Get input from the user and check that
    int numberOfElements = 0;
    if ((std::cin >> numberOfElements) and (numberOfElements > 0)) {

        // Create a vector to hold the data
        std::vector<int> arr(numberOfElements);

        std:: cout << "\n\nEnter the elements of the array:\n";
        // Read all values in a loop
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {

            // Read values and check, if it worked
            if (not (std::cin >> arr[i])) {
                std::cout << "\nError: Invalid input\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }

        // If we have valid input, then call function to give the result
        if (std::cin)
            std::cout << "\n\nMinimum absolute difference between any two distinct elements in the array is: " <<
            minAbsoluteDifference(arr) << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\nError: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```